# sqlite3 "OperationalError: unable to open database file" in python only when I deploy my flask app in apache2 or nginx

Tags: sqlite, flask, web-deployment

I made an app in flask that uses an sqlite3 database. The app works flawlessly when I run it using Flask's internal testing server. However, when I attempt to deploy my app, either using apache2 or gunicorn+nginx, and the logs of whatever server I'm using shows "OperationalError: unable to open database file".

Here is the full file that's causing the error:

```
import sqlite3

__all__ = ['Database']

class Database(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def _execute(self, command, args=None):
        connection = sqlite3.connect(self._name)
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        if args is None:
            out = cursor.execute(command).fetchall()
        else:
            out = cursor.execute(command, args).fetchall()

        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
        return out
```

The `connection = sqlite3.connect(self._name)` is the line that is actually triggering the error and I have no clue why. I have tried replacing `self._name` with a hard coded string to the path of the database to no avail. I have also made sure the database file has proper read write permissions.

Does anyone know how I can figure out what's going on?

Comment: What are the permissions on the file? Who is the owner of the file?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** Make sure the user launching the process has write permissions on the **parent folder** of the sqlite as well.

---

More details on how you deploy would be nice. Are you deploying using [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/)?

If you do, check the user you are using to deploy files has permissions. In fabric, that is the user you store in *env.user*. Use that very same user to launch the gunicorn server has permissions too.

You can follow this [example](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/fabric/) for a simple deployment script for a flask app.

Comment: could you please elaborate on the concept for deploying? I have same error, can connect to db on localhost, but not on EC2. I am not using fabric to deploy, I am just uploading my files. I would like to stick to simplicity before moving to fabric and other automation tool. How to define an env.user? Is it required?